# How do I fix "Cannot assign to read only property 'style' of object" in this React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I am creating an own custom tab component. It consists of a tab header which each has a body part. When a tab header is clicked, the corresponding body's style should be set to `display:block` and all others to `display:none`.

For some reasons I am getting this error:

> Cannot assign to read only property 'style' of object

I understand that I am not allowed to mutate the style property manually as it seems to be read-only but how do I fix/work around this?

Here is my code:

**Tabs.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Tabs extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      activeIndex: 0,
    };
    this.tabHeads = [];
  }

  // Initial composition of tab heads
  componentWillMount() {
    React.Children.map(this.props.children, (el, i) => {
      const tab = el;
      const key = `tabKey${i}`;
      this.tabHeads.push((
        <div role="button" onClick={e => this.onTabClick(e, i)} key={key}>{tab.props.title}</div>
      ));
    });
  }

  // Called when user clicks a tab head
  onTabClick(e, i) {
    this.setState({ activeIndex: i });
  }

  render() {
    // Set display none or block for each tab
    React.Children.map(this.props.children, (el, i) => {
      const tab = el;
      let visibility = 'none';
      if (i === this.state.activeIndex) visibility = 'block';
      const newStyle = Object.assign({}, tab.props.style, { display: visibility });
      tab.props.style = newStyle;
    });

    return (
      <div style={this.props.style}>
        {this.tabHeads}
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Tabs;
```

Usage is like this:

```
render() {
  const tabStyles = [
    { padding: '20px' }, // Tab 0
    { padding: '20px' }, // Tab 1
  ];

  <Tabs>

    <Tab style={tabStyles[0]} title="Tab1">
      <div>Content 1</div>
    </Tab>

    <Tab style={tabStyles[1]} title="Tab2">
      <div>Content 2</div>
    </Tab>

  </Tabs>
}
```

Comment: You can't reassign a prop to a different value. Props are read-only. Re-evaluate your design.

Comment: *"how do I fix/work around this?"* Clone the child: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You try to change property value in this line:
 `tab.props.style = newStyle;`
but  `props` in React are read-only and you can't manually change their values. Please check React [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only) for more details.
To fix it you can use [`React.cloneElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) which allow to clone element with new properties that will be merged into existing ones:

```
render() {
    let childrenWithNewProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (el, i) => {
        let visibility = 'none';
        if (i === this.state.activeIndex) visibility = 'block';
        return React.cloneElement(el, {
               style: {
                 display: visibility
               }
           }
        )
    });

    return (
          <div style={this.props.style}>
            {this.tabHeads}
            {childrenWithNewProps}
          </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hm, thanks the error is gone now but the style is not set. If I look into the component with `console.log(this.props.children)` I see that the component's style property is null. How do I fix this?

Comment: Answer updated - array with cloned elements  should be used in returned JSX

Comment: Nice but look this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52180309/stack-with-style-in-react-js. state.mySTyle is redaonly ...